# How does this facebook app got user's friends list through oauth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I am working with facebook graph and I believe that Facebook graph doesn't give access to users friends list but only total friends count is given on graph request in any of the present graph versions (2.0-2.7).

But this app has got over that restriction and it gets users friends list on oauth version 2.3 How did they got that ?

[Facebook App with friends list resource available(meaww.com)](http://meaww.com/activities/question/new_friends_family/2258?utm_source=Sidebar&utm_medium=Home&utm_campaign=NextActivity)

Did facebook made any exception for them or did I missed something ?

Comment: If users of your app have given you `user_friends` permission, than you can fetch all their friends that have also allowed and installed your app.

Comment: @Ognj3n..yeah.I know that but that's not the case here.The app gets all user friends info even though they haven't installed it.Check on Oauth with that app you can see your friends in oauth info box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not authorize those spam apps, just to be safe. Anyway, i assume they are using `taggable_friends` or `invitable_friends` - i am pretty sure they shouldn´t though. There is more information in this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: yeah,invitable_friends looks like the case here.I too won't authorize these apps but I was just analyzing that website because you will be shocked to see its traffic in 6 months since they launced :D